# Wowza sample link not working in android

Tags: android, wowza

I am doing to run wowza sample link in android. Wowza sample link is 
[here.](http://www.wowza.com/html/mobile.html) but it is not working in android.

My code is here.

HelloAndroidActivity(MainActivity)

```
public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private static String TAG = "androidEx2";

private Button buttonVideoSample;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    buttonVideoSample = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonVideoSample);
    buttonVideoSample.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonVideoSample) {
        String video_uri = "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov";
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, VideoSample.class);
        intent.putExtra("video_path", video_uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

Utils.java

```
public class Utils {
public static String durationInSecondsToString(int sec){
    int hours = sec / 3600; 
    int minutes = (sec / 60) - (hours * 60);
    int seconds = sec - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60) ;
    String formatted = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
    return formatted;
}
}
```

VideoSampleActivity

```
public class VideoSample extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener, Callback, OnPreparedListener, OnCompletionListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener,
    OnClickListener, OnSeekCompleteListener, AnimationListener {
private TextView textViewPlayed;
private TextView textViewLength;
private SeekBar seekBarProgress;
private SurfaceView surfaceViewFrame;
private ImageView imageViewPauseIndicator;
private MediaPlayer player;
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private ProgressBar progressBarWait;
private Timer updateTimer;
private Bundle extras;
private Animation hideMediaController;
private LinearLayout linearLayoutMediaController;
private static final String TAG = "log_tag";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.videosample);
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    linearLayoutMediaController = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutMediaController);
    linearLayoutMediaController.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    hideMediaController = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.disapearing);
    hideMediaController.setAnimationListener(this);

    imageViewPauseIndicator = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPauseIndicator);
    imageViewPauseIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (player != null) {
        if (!player.isPlaying()) {
            imageViewPauseIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    textViewPlayed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPlayed);
    textViewLength = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLength);

    surfaceViewFrame = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewFrame);
    surfaceViewFrame.setOnClickListener(this);
    surfaceViewFrame.setClickable(false);

    seekBarProgress = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarProgress);
    seekBarProgress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    seekBarProgress.setProgress(0);

    progressBarWait = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarWait);

    holder = surfaceViewFrame.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    player.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
    player.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
    player.setDisplay(holder);
}

private void playVideo() {
    if (extras.getString("video_path").equals("VIDEO_URI")) {
        showToast("Please, set the video URI in HelloAndroidActivity.java in onClick(View v) method");
    } else {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    player.setDataSource(VideoSample.this, Uri.parse(extras.getString("video_path")));
                    //player.setDataSource(extras.getString("video_path"));
                    //player.start();
                    player.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    showToast("Error while playing video");
                    Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    showToast("Error while playing video");
                    Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    showToast("Error while playing video. Please, check your network connection.");
                    Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}

private void showToast(final String string) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(VideoSample.this, string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    });
}

private void hideMediaController() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        linearLayoutMediaController.startAnimation(hideMediaController);
                    }
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    Log.i(TAG, "========== onProgressChanged : " + progress + " from user: " + fromUser);
    if (!fromUser) {
        textViewPlayed.setText(Utils.durationInSecondsToString(progress));
    }
}

public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
}

public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        progressBarWait.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        player.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress() * 1000);
        Log.i(TAG, "========== SeekTo : " + seekBar.getProgress());
    }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    playVideo();
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.i(TAG, "========== onPrepared ===========");
    int duration = mp.getDuration() / 1000; // duration in seconds
    seekBarProgress.setMax(duration);
    textViewLength.setText(Utils.durationInSecondsToString(duration));
    progressBarWait.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // Get the dimensions of the video
    int videoWidth = player.getVideoWidth();
    int videoHeight = player.getVideoHeight();
    float videoProportion = (float) videoWidth / (float) videoHeight;
    Log.i(TAG, "VIDEO SIZES: W: " + videoWidth + " H: " + videoHeight + " PROP: " + videoProportion);

    // Get the width of the screen
    int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int screenHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    float screenProportion = (float) screenWidth / (float) screenHeight;
    Log.i(TAG, "VIDEO SIZES: W: " + screenWidth + " H: " + screenHeight + " PROP: " + screenProportion);

    // Get the SurfaceView layout parameters
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = surfaceViewFrame.getLayoutParams();

    if (videoProportion > screenProportion) {
        lp.width = screenWidth;
        lp.height = (int) ((float) screenWidth / videoProportion);
    } else {
        lp.width = (int) (videoProportion * (float) screenHeight);
        lp.height = screenHeight;
    }

    // Commit the layout parameters
    surfaceViewFrame.setLayoutParams(lp);

    // Start video
    if (!player.isPlaying()) {
        player.start();
        updateMediaProgress();
        linearLayoutMediaController.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        hideMediaController();
    }
    surfaceViewFrame.setClickable(true);
}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.stop();
    if (updateTimer != null) {
        updateTimer.cancel();
    }
    finish();
}

/**
 * Change progress of mediaController
 * */
private void updateMediaProgress() {
    updateTimer = new Timer("progress Updater");
    updateTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    seekBarProgress.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition() / 1000);
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}

public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
    int progress = (int) ((float) mp.getDuration() * ((float) percent / (float) 100));
    seekBarProgress.setSecondaryProgress(progress / 1000);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.surfaceViewFrame) {
        if (linearLayoutMediaController.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            linearLayoutMediaController.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            hideMediaController();
        } else if (player != null) {
            if (player.isPlaying()) {
                player.pause();
                imageViewPauseIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                player.start();
                imageViewPauseIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
    progressBarWait.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

}

public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

}

public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    linearLayoutMediaController.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
}
```

Comment: That url plays fine in a VideoView on my Nexus 7.  I would try playing it on the main UI thread, if you have not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there would be room in comments...

The view:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/hls_frame"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video_player"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
/>
    <include layout="@layout/player_bar" />
</FrameLayout>
```

In the following code, the activity is passed in to a separate class (this would normally happen in the activity itself, but I need to support multiple players for older devices).  The method of interest:

```
public void loadPlayer() {
        _activity.setContentView(R.layout.hls_video_view);
        if (_activity.url == null) {
            Development.ExceptionMsg("Video Url is Null!");
            return;
        }
        VideoView view = (VideoView) _activity.findViewById(R.id.video_player);
        if (!_activity.isLive) {
            //MediaController for vod only
            MediaController controller = new MediaController(_activity);
            controller.setAnchorView(view);
            view.setMediaController(controller);
        }
        _activity.LogStreamStart();
        _activity.HideBuffering();
        view.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        view.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        view.setOnErrorListener(this);
        //this is important, and should perhaps be part of the interface
        view.setOnTouchListener(_activity);
        view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(_activity.url));
        view.requestFocus();
        view.start();
    }
```